# How to display a progress-spinner while fetching data via a Resolver in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, spinner, resolver, angular14

I'm using Angular 14 and PrimeNG 14.  In my module, I have the default route created, which is dependent on getting data from a resolver.  I would like the user to see a spinner until the data from the resolver comes back.  My route is set up like so ...

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve:{
      myData:MyResolver
    }
  } 
]
```

In the `my-component.ts` file, I attempt to set the loading state like so

```js
loading = true;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log("subscribing ...");
    this.router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
      this.checkRouterEvent((routerEvent as RouterEvent));
    });
}

checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: RouterEvent): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log("starting.");
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log("done.");
    }
}
```

And in the `my-component.html` file, I have:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="loading">
  <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="!loading">
...
</ng-template>
```

However, I never see the progress spinner.  Even if I bring down my endpoint, or disconnect from the Internet, which I woudl like would cause infinite spinning, there is no spinner on my page.  How do I fix this?

**Edit:** A demo of what is happening -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressspinner-demo-t2taze?file=src/app/app.module.ts .

Comment: But when you check the console-output, `console.log("starting.");` and `console.log("done.");` are working as expected and the to console.logs occur at least some milliseconds apart from each others?

Comment: And i you just put `<p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>` in your html (without NgIf) the spinner is showing correctly?

Comment: @kellermat, the spinner apperas (eventually) if I don't have an *ngIf statement in there.  "Eventually" meaning when the resolver has completed (it seems the component only initializes and renders within the module after the resolver completes).  I have included a demo link as an edit to my question.

Comment: I completely re-wrote my answer and updated my stackblitz-example (see below). I also included this actual fetching of the resolved data (see below).

Comment: Is quite interesting your use-case exporting module itself via module federation. Please post the code you get once you've solve it! I bet it would be helpful for a lot of people in the long run (as currently module federation is not widely used for most projects, but it'll be soon)

Answer (score 2):

### Display a progress-spinner while fetching data via a Resolver

Based on your stackblitz-example I revised my **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressspinner-demo-dm331o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** as well as my answer. Key facts:

- The **child**-component is not loaded until the route is completely
  resolved and therefore it cannot trigger the loading-spinner.
- As a consequence the **parent**-component (instead of the child) must track the start and the completion of the Resolver.
- Also the HTML code for the progress-spinner must be
  placed in the **parent**-component

---

**App-Module**:

I would recommend to define the entire route in the app-module, as long as we don't have feature-modules with lazy-loading (in the stackblitz example, the route is spread over two modules, because I didn't want to deviate too much from Dave's solution there).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ChildComponent,
    resolve: {
      myData: MyResolver,
    },
  },
];
```

**Parent-Component TS:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  unsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

  loading = true;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log('subscribing ...');
    this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((routerEvent) => {
        this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent as RouterEvent);
      });
  }

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: RouterEvent): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('starting.');
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log('done.');
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
  }
}
```

**Parent-Component HTML**:

`router-outlet` will not be loaded until the data is resolved.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="loading">
  <p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
</ng-template>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child-Component TS:**

Here the data from the resolver can be accessed synchronously, i.e. the data must already be resolved when the child component is loaded:

```
resolvedData: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  // Access the resolved data:
  this.resolvedData = this.route.snapshot.data.myData;

  // Subscribing to the Router would be worthless at this point,
  // since the data is already resolved.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this demo.  So the issue seems to occur within a module of the main application.  Using your demo, I created one of my own -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressspinner-demo-t2taze?file=src/app/app.module.ts .  You can see that no spinner appears for 5 seconds (the delay you put in), and then suddenly everything loads.

Comment: I completely re-wrote my answer as well as my stackblitz-example.

Comment: Thanks for working on that.  Unfortunately, it is not an option to move the resolver and other component logic to the app module (I'm exporting my module using module federation).  I need to keep all this contained to my custom module itself.

Comment: Maybe you should have mentioned this restriction in your question, it would have saved me quite some work... I guess what you are asking for is bascially impossible. Even if you used `skipLocationChange`, only the typescript-code of the child-component would be rendered before the resolver completes, yet the HTML would still not be rendered until it's too late for the progress-spinner to show up.

Comment: So despite the fact that Angular is now on version 14, it is not possible to use resolvers in a custom module?  I'm not reading anything about such a restriction in their documentation, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what resolvers are for.

Comment: I think the concept of a resolver is, that the component which expects the data, is not loaded before Resolver completes. I think this is conflicting with your idea of placing a loading-spinner in such a component? Btw: Maybe it's worth reading the following article (even though it's from September 2021, I think most of what's said there is still valid): https://anymindgroup.com/news/tech-blog/15141/#:~:text=So%20what%20is%20Angular%20Resolver,navigates%20to%20a%20particular%20component.

Comment: Btw: Even the official Angular-documentation states: 'The router waits for the data to be resolved before the route is finally activated.' Source: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Answer (score 0):

###### TLDR; Modify your approach, instead of "showing the spinner"; show it from the start and then hide it when load is finished. Take a look to [this working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressspinner-demo-wnjvfr?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

---

This can be done using a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4), in the example I called it `loaderService`, the main change is that your spinner has to be in `app.component` and later use the service methods `showLoader` and `hideLoader`. An advantage of this approach is that you'll use only one spinner for your entire application.

(I removed the parts of code I consider are unnecessary to explain the answer)

###### app.component.html

```html
<!-- `loading` flag starts in "true" so it's showed from the start -->
<p-progressSpinner *ngIf="loading"></p-progressSpinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

###### app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  unsubscribe = new Subject<void>();
  
  loading = true;
  constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    
    // service to show/hides the spinner
    this.loaderService.loader
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((flag) => {
         this.loading = flag;
    });
    // show loader for other routes navigation start
    this.router.events
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((routerEvent) => {
        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
          this.loaderService.showLoader();
        }
      });
  }
  ...
}
```

And then to implement it, you just call your loader as you will:

###### my.component.ts

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ...
  constructor(
    private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    ...
  }

  checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: RouterEvent): void {
    if (
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      routerEvent instanceof NavigationError
    ) {
     /**
      * hide it when finished, another use case covered here is 
      * that you can move this code to wait until XHR data has 
      * been loaded to hide it (not necessarily only when navigation ends)
      **/
      this.loaderService.hideLoader();
      console.log('done.', new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

###### loader.service.ts

```js
export class LoaderService {
  private _loader = new Subject<any>();
  public loader = this._loader.asObservable();
  ...

  showLoader() {
    this._toogleLoader(true);
  }

  hideLoader() {
    this._toogleLoader(false);
  }

  private _toogleLoader(flag: boolean) {
    this._loader.next(flag);
  }
}
```

---

This a really basic example and it should lead you along the way.

A complex one certainly will consider hiding background content while loading (for example when going between routes), and also would consider a better looking loader, like setting it `position: fixed`, centered and maybe using blurred content.

This is the approach I usually do in my projects. The `showLoader` call is usually triggered by another service I use for navigation.

Comment: You're including the spinner at the app.component.html, but this isn't going to work with my setup.  I need the spinner to be in the module because the module itself is getting exported via module federation.  If I need to include a spinner at the component invoking the module's component, I will have to duplicate that logic in all places where I import the module, which could be many.

Comment: I get it, another possibility would be to create the spinner from the service itself; would that work for you?

Comment: Sure I'd be open to that.

Comment: Not quite an easy task @Dave, [this link](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d) should lead you along the way. The final code should look like mine. But with code creating the dynamic spinner instead of using `loading` flag. Good luck